# Make: Weird behaviour of $(dir x/%) in static patterns if '%' is a directory

Tags: makefile

Using make, I wanted to create rules that create the target directory dynamically.
While working on it, I stumbled on a weird behavior that I didn't expect, I reduced it to this example:

```
a/b: %: | $(dir x/%)
```

Now, when I execute `make a/b`, I'd expect to get an error "`No rule to make target 'x/a/'`". However, I instead get "`No rule to make target 'x/'`".

The [documentation of the dir-function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#File-Name-Functions) clearly specifies that “The directory-part of the file name is everything up through (and including) the last slash in it.” So what am I missing here?

(Btw., in my case I can of course just do a `mkdir -p $(@D)`, but at this point I just want to know where I'm wrong here.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html) for pattern rules tries to make this behavior clear:

> Note that expansion using ‘%’ in pattern rules occurs **after** any variable or function expansions, which take place when the makefile is read.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that GNU Make expands the percentage sign only after the dir command has been evaluated. The reason is that expressions in prerequisites only are evaluated once while parsing the file and not each time the rule is used.

Here's an example where this behavior becomes obvious:

```
a/b: %: | $(error %)
```

`make a/b` now fails with `Makefile:1: *** %.  Stop.` instead of `Makefile:1: *** a/b.  Stop.` as you'd expect.